# How to show copy and paste menu items in flex 4 textinput?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In my flex 4 project I am using some Spark TextInput components. It doesn't show copy and paste in the right click menu by default. The user needs to copy some text and paste into it. How can we enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this information useful:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3612279

Basically, make sure that if you are using TextInput components inside a Panel or TitleWindow, make sure you set **mouseEnabled="true"**.  Both **PanelSkin** and **TitleWindowSkin** have **mouseEnabled="false"**.

I found that just setting **mouseEnabled="true"** on my TitleWindow solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, thats the answer of aour question.
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/30/copying-text-to-the-operating-system-clipboard-in-flex/

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new ContextMenu to add custom items to it and your not seeing the copy paste options, make sure that clipboardMenu=true on your ContextMenu object.